# Complexity of algorithm for cycle

Tags: time-complexity

i kindly ask you if you can confirm the complexity of that indipendent for cycle:

```
 for (x=2; x<logn; x++)
```

According me the complexity is bigtheta(n).

Thanks a lot for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this for loop finishes, `logn - 2` iterations will have been completed.

Thus, the complexity is actually `Θ(logn)`.

Comment: thanks chrk, but if i have something like this? for (z = 2^j; j>1; j=j/2) the complexity is still logn?